# How set up a certificate using Newman?

Tags: postman, newman

I've a collection of requests that are successfully executed on Postman. For these to work, I had to load a PFX certificate on the settings menu of Postman as well as to set up the passphrase. In addition, on each request, I had also to fill the Basic Authentication fields with a username and password. Well, no problem here.

Now, when I try to run the same collection on Newman I get the below error message:

```
write EPROTO 24504:error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1546:SSL alert number 42
```

I assume this is related with the certificate but I don't know how to deal with this in Newman.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards

Comment: Any help here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#client-certificates

Comment: Hi Danny! Thank you for the link but could you please detail with an example? Should I type "newman run nameOfCollection.json" followed by the CLI options "--ssl-client-cert"?  How do I point to the folder where the certificate is stored? what about the password of the certificate? In addition to the certificate, for this API, I also have a basic authentication (username/password). How do I use them here?

Comment: I've created a json file with the details of my certificate as I present below but got no joy. I used the command line with the following command: "newman run BasicOperations.postman_collection.json --ssl-client-cert-list certificate.json" but I got the same error. Below the content of the JSON certificate: [
 {
  "name": "My certificate",
  "matches": "testapi.xpto.com:443",
  "pfx": {
   "src": "/C:/Users/xpto/OneDrive/#01Folder/API/certificate_file_api.p12",
   "passphrase": "password_xpto"
  }
 }
]